# EJS variable always returns zero in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an .EJS file and the following code is written in it:

```
<% var sensor_data=0 %>

<%   var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://io.adafruit.com',
{
    username: "**********",
    password: "**********",
}
) 

client.on("connect",function(){
    console.log("connected");
}
)


var topic = `${client.options.username}/f/sensor`;

client.subscribe(topic, function(err){

    if(!err)
    console.log("subscribed");
});


client.on("message",function(topic,message){

    var sensor_msg = message.toString();
    sensor_data = parseInt(sensor_msg, 10)
    console.log(sensor_data);   //printing correct value
   
});

%>



<script>

function updateGauges()
{
    gauge1.value = <%= sensor_data %>; //something is wrong here
    console.log(<%= sensor_data %>);
}



gauge1 = new RadialGauge({ renderTo: 'gauge1',
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    units: '[units]', 
    title: "Sensor 1",
}).draw();



setInterval(updateGauges, 500);

</script>
```

I'm trying to assign value of sensor_data variable(EJS variable) to gauge1.value variable (JS variable) in the updateGauges() function but it always assign and prints zero. However, console.log(sensor_data) statement in the message receiving function is printing the correct value.

I have tried:

1. JSON.stringify
2. <%= sensor_data %>

but it still doesn't print or assign correct value in the script section.

Comment: "<%" and "%>" can you explain what that is? I haven't ever seen that backet enclosure?

Comment: Arent these used to write EJS code?

Comment: @user12326 What is the value of the message variable before it is converted into a string?